# Get text from a prompt alert using python selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page: https://foundation.app/@bryanmarktaylor. The problem I have is how to get the number to the left of the *copy to clipboard* button below the avatar (0x068C...). When I'm using python selenium webdriver with Chrome, instead of copying the number to the clipboard, the browser shows a [prompt alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCl2M.png) that says *Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter* and shows a textbox with the number I need.

I cannot inspect the code of the alert to catch the element. I've tried using

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
```

But it gives me

```
TypeError: send_keys() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I've also tried using a JS script

```
driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].getAttribute("value");""", alert)
```

but it looks like I cannot send the alert element as an argument

```
TypeError: Object of type Alert is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: well why didn't You find out how to pass arguments to `send_keys`, that should have been simple

Comment: I did. When dealing with a usual webelement, this line works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine alert to save the message:

```
driver.execute_script('window.alert = text => window.alertText = text')
// do something that triggers the alert
alert_text = driver.execute_script('return window.alertText')
```

Comment: When I do this, it throws an `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`